# Create javascript dates with timezone

Tags: javascript

I want to create javascript time with timezone instead of GMT

So with GMT Sydney time

```
var date = new Date('2019-05-17' + ' ' + '01:00' + ' GMT+10:00');
```

which works but during daylight saving days it changes to GMT+11:00
so i tried this which does not work

```
var date = new Date('2019-05-17' + ' ' + '01:00').toLocaleString("en-US", {timeZone: "Australia/Sydney"})
```

please tell me how do i do it correctly without adding/removing hours for daylight savings

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way to achieve what you want is to use the [momentjs timezone library](http://momentjs.com/timezone/). With it you can do something like this:

```js
const date = moment.tz("2019-05-17 10:00", "Australia/Sydney");
```

Comment: looks like wrong statement? moment.tz is not a function

Comment: @TestDjay - can you post the code.  Is this running in the browser or server?

Comment: browser and i tried this const dateee = moment("2019-05-17 03:00").tz("Australia/Sydney");

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Intl.DateTimeFormat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/DateTimeFormat) with custom options.

```js
// Set a date
const date = new Date();
// Set the datetime options
const opts = {
  year: 'numeric', month: 'numeric', day: 'numeric',
  hour: 'numeric', minute: 'numeric', second: 'numeric',
  timeZone: 'Australia/Sydney', timeZoneName: 'short'
};
// Set the formatted date
const audate = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-AU', opts).format(date);

document.write('Sidney, AU datetime is: ' + audate);
```

Comment: this returns as string